# Error when subscribing to operations through the java-client

Tags: cumulocity

When subscribing to operations using the Cumulocity java-client I am getting:
com.cumulocity.sdk.client.SDKException: unable to subscribe Client: fwy51ui5s1crhtn1p1qkybrl2me2  on Channel:/meta/subscribe 403:denied_by_security_policy:create_denied

My user has all the permissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually "/meta/subscribe 403:denied_by_security_policy:create_denied" is caused by subscribing to a non existing channel.

Comment: That was it! There was a typo in the ID of the agent I was subscribing to.

Comment: This post saved my time. I was pointing to a different org that did not have the event defined.